jquery how do you concatenate a variabe to an id
I want to delete a div with a dynamically created id.
i capture the id via the attr i.e
var rowToDelete = $(this).attr('data-name');

I then tried this:
 $(# " + rowToDelete + ").remove();

and this:
$(#rowToDelete").remove();

none worked. I am not concatenating the values correctly.
How do I correctly concatenate the value to the '#' .

You have to set # Selector as static string & rowToDelete variable as dynamic, like this :
$("#" + rowToDelete).remove();

OR
You can use template literals, like this :
$(`#${rowToDelete}`).remove();


You are messing up quotes, so there is syntax errors, check console.
You only need to quote # character (assuming data-name contains valid ID reference):
$('#' + rowToDelete).remove()

